# Vuejs RangeError: Invalid string length

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to `VueJS`, when I try to compile this code it works fine:

```
<template>
  <div id="users-table">
    <ServerTable url="users" :columns="columns" :options="options"></ServerTable>
  </div>
</template>
```

However when I add another tag (any tag) like that:

```
<template>
     <h1>Header</h1>
  <div id="users-table">
    <ServerTable url="users" :columns="columns" :options="options"></ServerTable>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am getting an error

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):
RangeError: Invalid string length
    at repeat$1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just put the whole content in a single root element.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div id="users-table">
      <ServerTable url="users" :columns="columns" :options="options"></ServerTable>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```